# Sign in with iCloud for iCloud Calendar on Android

Tags: android, swift, icalendar, android-calendar, caldav

I want to Create calendar android app that will show the user iCloud calendar event
after authentication with iCloud

How can we achieve sign in with iCloud in Android

I want to Create calendar android app that will show the user iCloud calendar event
after authentication with iCloud

How can we achieve sign in with iCloud in Android